# how do i keep FRED Nodes Connected

Tags: node-red

I have a raspberry pi3 collecting information and pushing to a cloud hosted instance on FRED.  I am using a cellular modem as there is no wifi at the location.  The cell service has to reconnect at times when connections are lost.  I have that configured to happen automatically but now I am having trouble keeping the FRED Nodes connected.  They will get disconnected and will try to reconnect 3 time and then lock out.  How do I set them up to go back and look again after a set period of time or do I need to set it up another way.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you should use MQTT, not the FRED node.

The FRED node has known issues with reconnecting after the connection drops. They won't likely be addressed in the FRED node because MQTT is a far better approach.

If you subscribe to FRED, you can use the MQTT service provided. If not, you can use any of a number of free MQTT services available. [There's a list on GitHub here](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/public_brokers) and a [Tutorial on using MQTT with Node-RED](http://noderedguide.com/node-red-lecture-3-basic-nodes-and-flows/)

Finally, if you don't want to lose data when the connection drops, Sense Tecnic has contributed a MQTT node which uses a local in memory database to cache data, then will continue sending data when the connection is restored. [mqttdb node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-mqttdb)

Comment: This is very helpful.  Ill check this out. Thx